# Visual Studio automatically deleting file on start up

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, visual-studio-2010

Yesterday I edited the Global.asax.cs file of an MVC project in Visual Studio 2010 and this morning when I opened Visual Studio the file was gone. Visual Studio had deleted the file on disk including my local changes.

I restored the file from source control and restarted Visual Studio and it again deleted the file on start up. The file appears in Solution Explorer initially while VS is initialising, and after about 5 seconds it disappears... VS deletes it from the disk. Source control shows it as missing.

I can reproduce this again and again.

Things I've tried:
- Repairing VS.
- Disabling ReSharper.
- Restarting my machine.
- Fresh source control checkout.
- Opening a different MVC project to see if the same thing happens there. It doesn't.

Anyone have any further ideas? Much abliged.

Comment: What source control are you using?

Comment: Have you tried creating a new branch from your latest commit with the Global.asax?